# Filter value on basis of data in grid

Tags: magento2

I have a custom grid in admin. I want to add a custom filter in this grid, which doesn't take value from database while filtering but from a particular column radius where data is set dynamically. Basically i want to modify the custom filter to take value from grid rather than from database. How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

**app/code/[Vendor]/[Module_Name]/Ui/DataProvider/Product/CustomColumnFilter.php**

```
<?php 
namespace [Vendor]\[Module_Name]\Ui\DataProvider\Product; 
class CustomColumnFilter implements \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface 
{ 
    public function addFilter(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection,
        $field,
        $condition = null
    ) 
    { 
        if (isset($condition['like'])) 
        { 
            $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

**app/code/[Vendor]/[Module_Name]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider"> 
        <arguments> 
            <argument name="addFieldStrategies" xsi:type="array"> 
                <item name="custom_column" xsi:type="object">[Vendor]\[Module_Name]\Ui\DataProvider\Product\CustomColumnField</item> 
            </argument> 
            <argument name="addFilterStrategies" xsi:type="array"> 
                <item name="custom_column" xsi:type="object">[Vendor]\[Module_Name]\Ui\DataProvider\Product\CustomColumnFilter</item> 
            </argument> 
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. but i think it sets default filter in the collection ,but my requirement are different